# Finding the mean of multiple arrays in a list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list with multiple arrays and I want to take the average of all the data points together. How can I do this? I have tried the following code below which gives me the mean for each array in the list instead.

```
cpw = [array([4.2, 4.1, 4.3, 4.3, 4.2, 4.3, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2, 4. ,
       4.1, 4.3, 4.1, 4.1, 4.4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2,
       4.4, 4.2]), array([4.1, 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4.1, 4. , 4. , 4.1, 4. , 4. , 4.1,
       4. , 4. , 4.1, 4. , 4. , 4.1, 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. , 4. ,
       4. , 4. ]), array([3.9, 3.8, 3.8, 3.9, 3.8, 3.8, 3.9, 3.8, 3.9, 3.9, 3.8, 3.9, 3.9,
       3.8, 3.9, 6.3, 3.8, 3.9, 3.9, 3.8, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.8, 3.9,
       3.8, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9]), array([3.7, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7,
       3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7]), array([5.1, 4.6, 4.5, 4.6, 4.6, 5.4, 4.6, 4.6, 4.5, 4.6, 4.6, 4.5, 4.6,
       4.6, 4.5, 4.6, 4.6, 4.5, 4.6, 2.6, 4.5, 5.4, 3.7, 4.5, 5.4, 1.7,
       4.5, 1.4, 4.7, 4.9, 5. , 7.3]),
for i in range(len(cpw)):
    output.append(np.mean(cpw[i]))
print(output)

[4.189285714285715, 4.021428571428571, 3.941935483870968, 3.7083333333333335, 4.49375, 4.2285714285714295, 4.400000000000001, 4.189285714285715, 4.021428571428571, 3.941935483870968, 3.7083333333333335,...
```

I am thinking a zip function is needed to unpack but I am unsure.

Comment: Take the mean of the output

Comment: `np.concatenate(cpw).mean()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is not too large, you can just concatenate the arrays and then calculate the mean. However, this will create copies of the full dataset, which might need a lot of memory if your data is larger.

In that case, calculate mean and length of each dataset and then do the weighted average of those.

```py
counts = [len(values) for values in cpw]
means = [values.mean() for values in cpw]
mean = np.average(means, weights=counts)
```

or with concatenation:

```py
np.concatenate(cpw).mean()
```

Comment: Or calculate the sum of sums and divide by the sum of lengths

Comment: That would be worse numerically.

Comment: How would it be worse? Have you tested?

Comment: First summing many numbers will lead to large numbers and thus rounding errors. Averaging ha better numerical properties.